# How to Adding Activities under “Activity History”

Tags: community, profile, page-layout, permission-sets

i would like to add below buttons on Activity History related list for a specific profile user.

1. Log a Call
2. Send an Email
3. Request Update

can any one help to achieve this requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Activity History is the same as Open Activities. The only way that items appear in the Activity History is if you close them. So from what I can understand is that you want to create Activities that are already closed?

There are multiple ways to do this but all require customisation. You can create a visualforce page using the apex:detail tag, write some javascript to create the button(s) and use a javascript url hack to prepopulate the close date to create closed tasks/activities.

But as far as I am aware there is no purely-configuration method to achieve this.

Comment: Actually my requirement is i want to add these buttons to activity history which is contact related list

Comment: Open Activities and Activity History are both related lists on the contact page layout, and they are both the same object. Open activities shows all activities that are currently open, and Activity History shows all activities that are closed (from the past).

Comment: thanks for your replay David Dawson.
now i am able to see mail merge and view all buttons but not log a call,send an email and request update buttons
could you please clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

This button / action visibility within a Lightning Community is controlled via the Global Publisher layout. If the Email action is not present on the layout then it will not display on the Activity History related list. You can confirm this by going doing the following:

```
Go to Setup > Global Actions > Publisher Layouts > Global Layout.
Edit the Global Layout.
Locate the Email Mobile & Lightning Action called "Email".
Add this to the Layout.
Save
```

Clear your browser cache and log back into the Community and access a record where the Send Email action was not present, it should now be restored.